# how can i make loop to print md5 for all the files in sha256_hashes_pack1

Tags: python

```
SHA256_HASHES_pack1 = [('md5.txt'), ('md51.txt'), ('SHA256-Hashes_pack2.txt')]

with open(SHA256_HASHES_pack1[2], 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
        if not data:
            break
        md5.update(data)
        sha1.update(data)
        
print("MD5: {0}".format(md5.hexdigest()))
print("SHA1: {0}".format(sha1.hexdigest()))
```

I am trying to retrain md5 of all files within the selected variable and it just prints for 1 thats when I do SHA256_HASHES_pack1[2] however I want it to print all the md5 for the files which I have listed in SHA256_HASHES_pack1 in 1 single go.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in SHA256_HASHES_pack2:
    with open(i, 'rb') as f:
        md5 = hashlib.md5()
        sha1 = hashlib.sha1()
        while True:
                data = f.read(BUF_SIZE)
                md5.update(data)
                sha1.update(data)
                if not data:
                    break
        print("MD5: {0}".format(md5.hexdigest()))
        print("SHA1: {0}".format(sha1.hexdigest()))
```

I have managed to make it work/